# Can we get the list of S3 buckets of specified region?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to filter the buckets depending upon the provided region.
The following is the code that I'm using, but it gives a list of all the buckets present on the S3 instance.

```
List<Bucket> buckets = s3Object.listBuckets();
String[] bucketsArray = new String[buckets.size()]; 
            for (int i = 0; i < buckets.size(); i++)bucketsArray[i] = buckets.get(i).getName();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

You would need to loop through each bucket and call `getBucketLocation()` to obtain its Region.

Comment: I don't want the bucket location but I want to list the buckets in a specified region. For example:-  if I give region name as "us-east-2", so only the buckets of that region should come in the response.

Comment: As per above, this is not possible. You would need to call `getBucketLocation()` for each bucket to determine its Region, and use that to filter your complete list of buckets.